# Can I use a javascript prototype to animate on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have this very simple function binding:

```
$('a.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
});
```

which replaces my chevron when I click a line of text. I thought about instead of replacing, animating the rotation of the chevron 90 degrees. I just read about prototypes and how you can add a function to all objects of that prototypes at the same time. My question (since I'm new to prototypes) is can I create a prototype from a jquery selector and add a function to it?

Something like,

```
DropdownArrow = $('a.accordion-toggle')
DropdownArrow.prototype.turn = function(){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd toggle a class on click which animates the icon, for example:

**JS**

```
$('a.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.glyphicon').toggleClass('rotate-icon');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate-icon{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

[I've created a pen to show the animation working](http://codepen.io/suth_a/pen/OVYmOv)

**Update**

I forgot to mention that you'll need to add a transition to the element you're animating to create a nice smooth animation effect, for example:

```
a {
    transition: 350ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.6,0.2,0.7);
}
```

you can also use ease-in/ease-out etc for the easing part but here I'm using cubic-bezier which gives you finer control over easing - [here's a tool you can use to play around/learn about it](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67)

Comment: Is the prototype way not possible, not preferred, or just not the right way of doing it? This definitely looks like a better way to do it, but I guess I'm just trying to learn when to use a prototype.

Comment: I've not done it using prototype but it looks like an unnecessarily complex way of doing it since CSS can take care of the animation, CSS animations are awesome and unless you're doing a lot of animations at once then just as fast as JS

Answer (score 2):

You can, but like this:

```
$.prototype.turn = function(){
  //your function
}

$('a.accordion-toggle').turn();
```

Comment: So that would add a turn function to the jquery object? I guess I never thought of that.

Comment: Yes it will, so then you can call it anytime.

Comment: Cool. Say I wanted to have it only for that one type of object... would I have to create a class or something?

Comment: That is, only use for an anchor object??

Comment: Right. Like if I only want turn for specific objects?

Comment: No, (or) I don't recommend. It will be preferable to create a jQuery plugin then.